# Why can't the equation with the angle between vectors be solved?

Tags: equation-solving

```
n1 = {6 - 8 m, -2 + 8 m, 4}; n2 = {2, 2, 4};
Solve[VectorAngle[n1, n2] == 150 Degree, m, Reals]
```

Why can't the equation with the angle between vectors be solved?

[image]

Comment: No solution. `n1 = {6 - 8 m, -2 + 8 m, 4}; n2 = {2, 2, 4};
Reduce[VectorAngle[n1, n2] == 150 Degree` is `False`

Comment: `Plot[VectorAngle[n1, n2], {m, -5, 5}  , PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-0.2, 3}}  , GridLines -> {None, {5 π/6}}  , GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
n1 = {6 - 8 m, -2 + 8 m, 4}; n2 = {2, 2, 4};
FunctionRange[VectorAngle[n1, n2], m, z]
```

> `0 <= z < π/2`

It means that `z=VectorAngle[n1, n2]==150 Degree` without solution.

```
n1 = {6 - 8 m, -2 + 8 m, 4}; n2 = {2, 2, 4};
Reduce[n1 . n2/(Sqrt[n1 . n1] Sqrt[n2 . n2]) == Cos[150 Degree]]
```

> `False`